# quantum computers able to see the future

Tags: computers, quantum

when quantum computers become able to calculate quantum calculations, would that equal a psychic? Because wouldn't it be able to calculate possible future events at such a % it would become a true psychic device?

Comment: Sorry but I don't see how this question about Worldbuilding? Is it not more appropriate for a technology or physics site.

Comment: The difference between classical computers and quantum computers is that quantum computers will be able to perform *some* non-deterministic algorithms more efficiently than ordinary deterministic computers. This means that *some* problems can be solved in polynomial time which would require exponential time on classical computers. For example, *some* encryption schemes can be cryptanalized efficiently using quantum computers; but not all, and I bet that when quantum computers will become available all web servers will use quantum-resistant encryption. Quantum does not mean "magical".

Comment: In Quantum mechanics, the future is non-deterministic. That means all we can talk about are probabilities. With the help of a better computer we can calculate a probability of, for example, election outcome much better that we do today - but it will still be a probability, not certainty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One statement about QC's I walked upon was "if you wish to simulate the evolution of a large quantum system, you'd rather build this very system and watch how it evolves, that would cost less than modelling it on a conventional supercomputer". So forget about predictions for systems like brain and so on. QC's won't necessarily be good at predictions at all, that will depend on simultaneous existence of mathematical models adapted for quantum computing and quantum algorithms that can solve the model equations. This area is too brand new yet, but eventually it may develop some sort of a social or economic quantum models.